# Load Java JNA native library in Node

Tags: java, node.js, jna

I'm running a JNA compiled native library through [node-java] wrapper for Node.js [1](https://github.com/joeferner/node-java)

The library is [Hunspell JNA](https://github.com/dren-dk/HunspellJNA) that wraps the hunspell spelling library.

In my simplest test

```
     var instance=java.callStaticMethodSync("dk.dren.hunspell.Hunspell","getInstance");
     console.log( instance );
```

what happens is that node seems to hang when trying to load the native library from the lib path:

```
hsl = (HunspellLibrary)Native.loadLibrary(libFile, HunspellLibrary.class);
```

in [this](https://github.com/dren-dk/HunspellJNA/blob/master/src/dk/dren/hunspell/Hunspell.java#L85) method, so it seems to be a JNA problem when calling the `loadLibrary` method.

The library is there, and I have also tried the second option of that method to copy in a temporary folder and load from there, so I can see

```
Loading temp lib: /var/folders/_b/szqwdfn979n4fdg7f2j875_r0000gn/T/jna5370593161365499003.libhunspell-darwin-x86-64.dylib
```

that it is there.

Comment: Can you get a JVM thread dump?

Comment: @technomage do you mean a dump while running i.e. when the run hangs?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's the data it's receiving and is it receiving any?

getInstance(String libDir)
The instance of the HunspellManager, looks for the native lib in the directory specified.

from man(1) hunspell:
The default dictionary depends on the locale settings. The following environment variables are searched: LC_ALL, LC_MESSAGES, and LANG. If none are set then the default personal dictionary is $HOME/.hunspell_default.

Hope it helps.

Comment: So, the default dictionary it is ok (it's in the path), and it works when loaded from java like: `java -cp lib/jna.jar:build/jar/hunspell.jar     -Droot=/data/data/dictionaries -Dlang=en_GB dk.dren.hunspell.HunspellMain`. The problem from node, it seems to be the native library loading through JNA method (static) `Native.loadLibrary(path,class)`.